# Incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *' error in 2d array

Tags: arrays, c, string, struct, typedef

I found questions for similar errors having `char[100];` but they didn't help me. I only know some basic C language.

This is my C code to store a person's name and number in a 2D array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct {
   char name[100][100];
   char number[100][100];
}
person;

int main(void) {
    setvbuf(stdout,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    setvbuf(stderr,NULL,_IONBF,0);
    person people[3];
    int i;
    people[0].name = "Abu";
    people[0].number = "+91-123456789";
    people[1].name = "Tony";
    people[1].number = "+1-4432788878";
    people[2].name = "Simon";
    people[2].number = "+42-432432233";
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
        if(strcmp(people[i].name,"Simon")==0){
            printf("Found %s\n",people[i].number);
            return 0;
        }
    }printf("Not found\n");
    return 1;
}
```

This program shows 6 error and 2 warnings:

```
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[100][100]' from type 'char *'
   typedef struct sample.c:31:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strcmp'
   typedef struct sample.c:32:4: warning: format '%s' expects type 'char *',
   but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[100]'
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code, in the lines like the following:

```c
people[0].name = "Abu";
```

First, you cannot copy C-style character strings like this. Let's look at a simple example:

```c
char dest[100]; // An array of 100 characters;
dest = "This is what I want in 'dest'."; // Error!
```

The error here is that the RHS of the assignment evaluates to the *address of* the given string literal and the LHS is an array (which is not a type that can be assigned to).

In this case, you use the `strcpy` function, like so, to **copy the data** from the RHS into the array of the LHS:

```c
char dest[100]; // An array of 100 characters;
strcpy(dest,"This is what I want in 'dest'.");
```

However, in your code, there is another problem: The `name` and `number` fields of the `person` structure are defined as **two dimensional** arrays of characters (that is, each is an array of 100 *strings*). I can't see any reason why you would want this – presumably, each person has only one name and one number (and you have multiple `person` objects in the `people` array).

So, I would suggest that you redefine your `person` structure to have only a single (100 character) string for each field, like so:

```c
typedef struct {
    char name[100];     // Allows up to 99 characters for each name and number...
    char number[100];   // ... 'reserving' one `char` for the REQUIRED nul terminator
} person;
```

Then you can copy your data to each field with lines like the following:

```c
strcpy(people[0].name, "Abu");
strcpy(people[0].number, "+91-123456789");
strcpy(people[1].name, "Tony");
//... and so forth
```

---

Note: If you *do actually* require multiple names and numbers for each person, then you will need to add the index of the `name` or `number` field in the call to `strcpy`:

```c
strcpy(people[0].number[0], "+91-123456789"); // Sets Abu's FIRST number
strcpy(people[0].number[1], "+91-987654321"); // Sets Abu's SECOND nmuber
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped me . But i had assigned string values to 2D array as here "char names[100][100] = {"Abu","Simon"};" from this i can print name by "printf("Name : %s",names[1]);" without using strcpy, how can i do this here.

Comment: *Without using strcpy* ... then you would have to copy each character individually, which is, effectively, writing your own version of strcpy. That's what strcpy is for.

Comment: @TheophinJohnson You also seem to be confusing the 'second' dimension inside your structure with the array of structures itself. Do you really want multiple names for a single person?